# How to best handle fling gesture for Android ListActivity

Tags: android, gestures

I have an Android app with a `ListActivity` in the main view. The list contains a `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` and a hidden delete Button. The delete Button will be hidden by default. I want to use a fling gesture to show the button.  I am able to detect the fling gesture thanks to question #[937313](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313) on stackoverflow. It's not clear to me how to determine which item in the list was flung, since the onTouch listener listens to the `ListView`. The item is not necessarily selected so getSelected* methods can't be used reliably. I am using the `SimpleListAdaptor` so I don't have direct access to the View Objects in the `ListView`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using [AbsListView.pointToPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#pointToPosition(int,%20int)) to determine the list item for the X,Y coordinate in your list view.

If you're using the recipe from #[937313](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313), you should be able to override `onFling()` more or less as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(listAdapter.getItem( listView.pointToPosition( (int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY() ).toString() );
        return super.onFling();
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: *pointToPosition()* takes int and not float as arguments so use *Math.round(e1.getX()), Math.round(e1.getY())* instead of directly using *e1.getX(), e1.getY()*