# Android - ListView fling gesture triggers context menu

Tags: android, gesture

I'm relatively new to Android development. I'm developing an app with a ListView. I've followed the info in #[1338475](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338475/how-to-best-handle-fling-gesture-for-android-listactivity) and have my app recognizing the fling gesture, but after the gesture is complete, it pulls up the context menu for the item. I just want the fling action to be handled in code (my app does one list per date and I want to use the fling gesture to move back and forth in days). Does anyone know how to suppress the context menu if the gesture is recognized?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Returning `True` from `onFling(...)` doesn't actually solve this problem. it turns out that onFling only consumes the `ACTION_UP` event which makes the listview still think the view is still being pressed. See this bug report for more info [https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8497](code.google.com/p/android/issues/...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return value in your overrided `onFling` method.

You need to return "true" in order to consume the event, if you do not consume the fling event, it will be passed back up through the android system and possibly trigger other events such as the `onLong` (context menu) event.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out to be two problems:
1) I didn't return True.
2) I was using the emulator, which is apparently a bit sluggish on my box.