# Getting row position of listview on swipe

Tags: android, listview, gesture-recognition, swipe-gesture

I know this type of question is asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6597883/626481).
 I have tried both gesture detector :

```
 wholelistview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**which detects only swipe(cannot get row position here).**

similarly in getview:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//other stuff

convertview.setOnTouchListener(same as above);

}
```

but **cannot detect swipe.**

Any solution for this ???
I want only the row position on which swipe is made.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373485/android-swipe-on-list anyways..Happy Birthday To You!

Comment: @Frankenstein I have seen this already.But how can i get row position from this.

Comment: I don't know exactlly but using this http://software-workshop.eu/content/swiping-listview-elements you can do swipe right? there you are getting View v as argument can't you do getTag there to know the view's tag and set it during your list createion getView() method do setTag() there..this way using set and getTag() you might can achieve this..try

Answer (score 3):

hanry what kind of errors do you get? I've implemented it and it works perectly. But instead of storing the position of the element I'm storing the view holder that among the others also have the model property. Remember that you have to check if the convertview isn't null. Take a look at the code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    Model m = filter.subItems.get(position);
    if(m != null)
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.position = position; - here you can put your position.
            view.setOnTouchListener(this.listener);
            //assign whatever you like to the viewHolder - in most cases the model and inlated controls and then assign 
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
```

and then

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = ((ViewHolder) v.getTag());
}
```

hop that helps.
ps: If you don't know anything about view holders and tags I suugest to see [there](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_performance). And my approach has been described in the link that Frankenstein gave.

Comment: on which I should implement ontouchlistener full listview or convertview???? as i cannot detect touch/swipe

Comment: I'm attaching to the view in the Adapter.
    view.setOnTouchListener(this.listener);
I'm doing it only if the converview is null, after inflating new view.

Comment: +1 i m getting row position on touch but **(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))** is not called.

Comment: I've had some issues with the gesturedetector as well, that's why I stopped using it.

Answer (score 1):

To get row position for your view, get position of view passed by onTouch for your listview by this function

```
wholelistview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {                 
 if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
    int position =  indexOfChild(View v);

     return true;                 
     }                 
     return false;             
                  }         });
```

It returns index of child.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.indexOfChild%28android.view.View%29

Comment: can you explain it more as i can't use indexofchild it says:Multiple markers at this line
 - View cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Syntax error on token "v", delete this

Comment: I have not tried it, and right now can not try this... I will try and tell you once @ home

Answer (score 1):

you can do getTag and setTag to know the tag of the view and using that you can decide which row has been swiped

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
//other stuff 
     convertview.setTag(position);
}
```

and for **[swipe](http://software-workshop.eu/content/swiping-listview-elements)** from the link

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     int pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
     Log.i(TAG,pos+" is swiped");
 }
```

I didn't Implemented this..so you will have to test for error..but According to me this can be a good way to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int position = -1;
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int index, long id) {
position = index;
}
```

like this?