# Swipe and change layout of an element of a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe-gesture, swipeview

I am trying to achieve the following effect on my custom list-view: When the user swipes the list element to right the layout of the swiped list item would change its layout. I have tried the SwipeListView approach from GitHub but i didn't manage to implement that through.

Can you give me any ideas on how to achieve the desired effect?
Also please note that i used a merge adapter for a list-view with multiple headers and sections.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597883/swipe-detection-for-each-row-of-listview) and the links that it provides to give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks, i finally chose a solution which combines the ViewPager and ListView widgets.